# Query where column values are equal

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.x

I have the following query:

```
$drivers = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Drivers');
$driver = $drivers->find()->where(['user_id' => $userId])->first();
return $drivers->find()->where(['user_id' => $userId])
    ->contain([
        'Users',
        'Championships' => [
            'Races' => [
                'Results' => [
                    'strategy' => 'select',
                    'queryBuilder' => function (Query $query) use ($driver) {
                        return $query->where(['driver_id' => $driver->id]);
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->first();
```

I want to know if it's possible to combine them. I thought this would be possible:

```
$drivers = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Drivers');
return $drivers->find()->where(['user_id' => $userId])
    ->contain([
        'Users',
        'Championships' => [
            'Races' => [
                'Results' => [
                    'strategy' => 'select',
                    'queryBuilder' => function (Query $query) {
                        return $query->where(['driver_id' => 'Drivers.id']);
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->first();
```

However, it throws a `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Drivers.id' in 'where clause'` error.

Is it possible to combine and how would I do it?

Comment: That equation shouldn't work, as the right hand side of a `key => value` condition will always be subject to escaping/casting/binding (unless it's an expression). Are you sure that you are showing your actual code?

Comment: I understand the equation won't work, but that's why I'm asking if there is a way to combine the above block of code? This is my actual code (the first part). The second block is what I tried initially.

Comment: Let's say the condition would work, and you'd get a `Results.driver_id = Drivers.id` SQL snippet, then the error would be the result of the `Results` association (and possible others) not being joined, but selected in a separate query (check DebugKits SQL log). But the thing is, you shouldn't get that error with that condition, both queries are basically the same, it's just that `driver_id` would be compared to a casted string instead of an integer. So I assumed that either the error stems from somewhere else, or that this isn't the exact code that produces that error, hence I'm asking.